# pandas resample with BM

Tags: python, pandas

I have a question on pandas resample with BM frequency.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np



ccc = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start='20160101', end='20161230', freq='BM'), data = np.arange(12))

ccc:
             0
2016-01-29   0
2016-02-29   1
2016-03-31   2
2016-04-29   3
2016-05-31   4
2016-06-30   5
2016-07-29   6
2016-08-31   7
2016-09-30   8
2016-10-31   9
2016-11-30  10
2016-12-30  11
```

When I resample it with '2BM':

```
ccc.resample('2BM').sum()

             0
2016-01-29   0
2016-03-31   3
2016-05-31   7
2016-07-29  11
2016-09-30  15
2016-11-30  19
2017-01-31  11
```

I don't understand why the first period 2016-01-29 would be left alone? (as opposed to be grouped with 2016-02-29 in the resampling)

Answer (score 2):

There are [closed and loffset](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html#pandas-dataframe-resample) parameters that control this feature.

```
ccc.resample('2BM',closed='left',loffset='-1BM').sum()

2016-02-29  1
2016-04-29  5
2016-06-30  9
2016-08-31  13
2016-10-31  17
2016-12-30  21
```